# Параллельный запуск автотестов с одинаковыми ролями pytest

Tags: python, test-automation, pytest

Дано:

- веб-приложение, которое допускает только одно нахождение на сайте (т.е. при запуске второго браузера и авторизации в нем, первого выкидывает)
- допустим, 40 автотестов
- фикстура, в которой происходит авторизация пользователя
- несколько тестовых пользователей.

Так вот, тестовый прогон 40 тестов занимает долгое время, решено было запускать через `pytest -n4`. Это запускает тесты в 4 потока, но они падают по причине повторной авторизации, соответственно, вопрос - как правильно реализовать параллельный запуск тестов?

Тестовые пользователи хранятся так:

```
TESTER_01_L = os.getenv('USER_TESTER_01')
TESTER_01_P = os.getenv('USER_TESTER_01_PASSWORD')
TESTER_01_E = os.getenv('USER_TESTER_01_EMAIL')

USER_MAIN_L = os.getenv('USER_MAIN')
USER_MAIN_P = os.getenv('USER_MAIN_PASSWORD')
USER_MAIN_E = os.getenv('USER_MAIN_EMAIL')
```

Фикстура авторизации выглядит так:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
@allure.title('Авторизация пользователя')
def authorization(open_env):
    driver = open_env
    login_obj = LoginForm(driver)
    account_obj = Account(driver)
    with allure.step('Заполнить поле "Логин или email"'):
        login_obj.focus_on_login_and_input(USER_MAIN_L)
    with allure.step('Заполнить поле "Введите пароль"'):
        login_obj.focus_on_password_and_input(USER_MAIN_P)
    with allure.step('Нажать кнопку "Начать работу"'):
        auth_button = driver.find_element(*login_obj.id_login_button)
        auth_button.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    with allure.step('Ожидать появления email пользователя при авторизации'):
        login_obj.wait_element_present(account_obj.user_email[1])
    yield driver
    with allure.step('Нажать "Перейти к сметам"'):
        main_tab = MainTab(driver)
        btn_back_to_est = driver.find_element(*main_tab.back_to_estimates)
        main_tab.click(btn_back_to_est)
    with allure.step('Вызвать меню, нажав на почту пользователя'):
        btn_email = driver.find_element(*account_obj.user_email)
        account_obj.click(btn_email)
    with allure.step('Нажать "Выйти из аккаунта"'):
        btn_logout = driver.find_element(*account_obj.logout)
        account_obj.click(btn_logout)
```

Comment: Если есть набор пользователей, то идти по списку пользователей, пробовать через каждого подключиться, если получилось подключиться - возвращаете подключение. Если дошли до конца, пробуем с начала списка.

Comment: @insolor, так оно в любом случае вернет подключение, просто выкинет из сессии того, кто раньше зашел

Comment: Тогда нужно как-то локально запоминать, какие пользователи заняты. Например файл создавать, проверять наличие этого файла, при завершении файл удалять.